# How to view additional diffs for only files that were modified after already staging them in git

Tags: git

Is there a way to do a `git diff` but where you can show the diffs of *only* modified files that were *previously* staged.

I.e. say this is my current git status below - you can notice that `file1` was previously staged and shows up in the top staged section. And then I made some changes to `file1` which is why it now also shows up in the bottom unstaged section.

```
╰─❯ git status
On branch himat/x
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   path/to/file1.sql
        modified:   path/to/file2.sql
        modified:   path/to/file3.sql
        modified:   path/to/file4.sql

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   path/to/file1.sql # — NOTE this file that was previously changed
        modified:   path/to/file4.sql # — NOTE this file that was previously changed
        modified:   path/to/file5.sql
```

If I do a `git diff`, I'll see the changes for ALL files 1, 4, 5. This is not what I want.
I want to see *only* the additional changes for files `1` and `4` as those are the ones I modified again after previously staging them.

Furthermore, as an extra comparison if helpful, I know I can do `git update-index --again` to re-add only updated files that were already staged, so this would add the additional changes to only files 1 and 4 to the stage too.
So I basically want a counterpart to this but for `git diff`.

Is this built-in anywhere like it is for `update-index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know:

1. `git diff` with no arguments compares the worktree with the index
2. `git diff --cached` compares the index with the HEAD commit
3. `git diff --name-only` will only print the names of differing files, instead of printing the full patch

To restrict `git diff` (see the differences worktree vs index) only for staged files (list of files in index vs HEAD), simply combine the 3 options above:

```
# show the regular 'git diff', only on files listed by 'git diff --cached'
git diff $(git diff --cached --name-only)
```

---

`git diff --name-only` will list full paths from the root of the repository, add `--relative` to the file listing command if you want to make it work from within any subdirectory of your repo:

```
git diff $(git diff --cached --relative --name-only)
```

Comment: Wow that's actually very elegant (I had started writing a full bash function with a loop), thank you so much! My new favorite command now.

Comment: It actually works for me from within any subdir even without the `--relative` fyi

Comment: One issue with this is that if there are no files currently staged, then running this will actually result in a regular `git diff` with no arguments, which ends up being confusing since you would expect to see nothing printed out in this case. I did this workaround to check if there are any staged files first `git diff --staged --quiet --exit-code || git diff $(git diff --staged --relative --name-only)`, but let me know if there's a better way

Answer (score 1):

Just do it. You're interested in files with changes in both the indexed and the work tree copies, so:

```bash
( git diff-index --name-only --cached @     # indexed aka tracked files different in index and HEAD aka @
  git diff-files --name-only                # files that differ in the index and work tree
) | sort | uniq -d
```

So that's files whose staged aka cached aka indexed aka added aka tracked version is not the checked-out commit's version, and whose work tree version is also not the staged aka etc version, so you added a new revision and then further changed that in the work tree.

Now you just want to see the diffs, that's just using the list that generated as paths for `git diff-files -p`,

```bash
( IFS=$'\n' # expansion args split only at newlines
  git diff-files -p $(
        ( git diff-index --name-only --cached @
          git diff-files --name-only
        ) | sort | uniq -d
  )
)
```

If you've got a monster work tree you can improve the hunt by restricting the diff-files to check just the paths with staged changes but it scarcely seems worth it.